# Remove animation from child component in React Native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I have a sticky header in a FlatList that scales and translates Y property on scroll. I want to have a component inside and on top of the image, however, I want this component to be at the bottom of the animated image at all times. (absolute position). I've tried the below however, the scale of my AnimatedImage is being applied to the inside component. How can I have it not scale?

Heres the code;

```
<AnimatedImageBackground
  source={{ uri: venue.image_URL }}
  style={{
    flex: 1,
    height: HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT,
    resizeMode: "cover",
    transform: [translateYStyle, scaleStyle],
  }}>
    <View
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        bottom: 0,
        zIndex: 9999,
        alignSelf: "center",
        marginBottom: 10,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        paddingVertical: 5,
        borderRadius: 5,
        opacity: 0.5,
      }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 17 }}>Photos</Text>
    </View>
</AnimatedImageBackground>
```

Comment: A transformation like scaling or translating always effects an element, and everything it contains. You can not "turn it off" for children, you can only either try and apply the exact "reverse" of the transformations you applied to the parent (not always easy to do, and doesn't always give pleasing results) - or move the "child" out of the parent you apply these to, to begin with.